# 'NoneType' object is not iterable - looping w/returned value

Tags: python, python-2.7

The purpose of this code is to find the longest string in alphabetical order that occurs first and return that subset.

I can execute the code once, but when I try to loop it I get 'NoneType' object is not iterable (points to last line).  I have made sure that what I return and input are all not of NoneType, so I feel like I'm missing a fundamental.

This is my first project in the class, so the code doesn't need to be the "best" or most efficient way - it's just about learning the basics at this point.

```
s = 'efghiabcdefg'
best = ''
comp = ''
temp = ''

def prog(comp, temp, best, s):
    for char in s:
        if comp <= char: #Begins COMParison of first CHARacter to <null>
            comp = char  #If the following character is larger (alphabetical), stores that as the next value to compare to.
            temp = temp + comp  #Creates a TEMPorary string of characters in alpha order.
            if len(temp) > len(best):  #Accepts first string as longest string, then compares subsequent strings to the "best" length string, replacing if longer.
                best = temp
            if len(best) == len(s):  #This is the code that was added...
                return(s, best)  #...to fix the problem.  
        else:
            s = s.lstrip(temp)  #Removes those characters considered in this pass
            return (str(s), str(best)) #Provides new input for subsequent passes

while len(s) != 0:
    (s, best) = prog(comp, temp, best, s)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation; where does the `prog` function end?

Comment: Also, your `break` in the `else` block is useless. The execution will stop when it hits `return`.

Comment: And can you include the *full traceback* of the error?

Comment: Since this is python, indenting is **semantic** and not only aesthetic. So, fix your indentation. Also, are you sure that all code paths in your function return a value?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I am trying to learn how to do the full traceback now.  This is week 1 for me.

Comment: The code posted here doesn't produce a traceback. Instead I get `s = 'abcdefg'` and `best = 'efghi'` back.

Comment: When I call this function, it returns ('abcdefg', 'efghi') which seems to be pretty good for finding alphabetically ordered characters.

Comment: @Trevor `import traceback` then put all of your code inside a `try` / `except` block and put `print traceback.format_exc()` under `except:`

Comment: That's my fault, I accidentally pasted the test version.  'if' should be 'while'.  I have updated it.

Comment: So, the idea is that it would return those values that you identified, then run it back through for another pass.  The expected output is 'best = abcdefg' because that string is longer and in alpha order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prog` is returning `None`. The error you get is when you try to unpack the result into the tuple (s, best)

You need to fix your logic so that `prog` is guaranteed to not return `None`. It will return `None` if your code never executes the `else` clause in the loop.

Comment: That fixed it!  Thank you for helping me understand what was going wrong.  By adding:

    if len(best) == len(s)
        return(best)

...before the else I am able to get my expected result.  

If I had 15 reputation I would upvote you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't `return` in all cases. In Python, if a function ends without an explicit `return` statement, it will return `None`.

Consider returning something if, for example, the input string is empty.